# How to limit the number of rows for a specific foreign key in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

In my Django project, I have `Store` and `Image` tables. As each store has 12 images, I use store foreign key to connect 12 images to a certain store in `Image` table.

I would like to limit the possible number of images to a certain store to be 12. In `Store` table, I used `unique=True` to avoid duplicates. However, in `Image` table, it's kind of different with duplicates because I want to limit 12 images for a certain store.

Is it possible in Django admin?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be to override your [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method of Image Admin.

So while adding a new image you can check if a certain store has more then 12 images with the help of foreign key relationship you mentioned. If the number exceeds you may show some error message to the user, otherwise save it.

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail in `save_model` please? I didn't get any hang of it yet :(

Comment: Please provide your Image and store models.